# How to "fix" the "top" directory in a SWT FileDialog

Tags: eclipse, swt

With eclipse 4.4 luna, how to open a org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog and set  the top directory the user will be allowed to navigate.

In other words, open a FileDialog on an initial directory, and the user can only select a descendent (child, grandchild etc) of this directory, but nothing outside of the directory (ancestors or siblings)

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

There is an Eclipse bug [15891](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15891) dating back to 2002 requesting this feature but it is closed as 'won't fix'.

You could write your own dialog using a TreeViewer and the Java file APIs.

Comment: Thanks. It's a shame it's not a feature of FileDialog... I'll try now to find such FileDialog on the web. I don't want to spend days just for this...